# Как правильно в JS организовать фильтрацию ввода с клавиатуры: отделить буквы от цифр и прочих символов, в моём случае?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужна помощь в контексте JS либо JQuery.

Работаю с event.key.
Повозился с typeof, но видимо не то. А может быть не так возился. В общем, я пока продолжаю, а задача такая - нужно выводить на экран только буквы.

При нажатии клавиши я генерирую элемент списка (со взятым у события значением нажатой клавиши) и внедряю его в список. Вот эти самые значения я и пытался отфильтровать.

Была идея использовать event.code, задавая в условии проверки диапазон кодов клавиш, но в русском и английском языках разное количество букв, поэтому метод работал БЫ, если бы можно было дополнительно устроить проверку языка ввода (было бы 2 набора диапазонов).

Код:

```
//VARS

let list = document.querySelector('ul');


//FUNCTIONS

function addLetter(event){
    let code = event.key;
    //console.log(code);
    if(something){
        list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${code}</li>`);
    }
};

//LISTENERS

document.addEventListener('keydown', addLetter);
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Код есть?

Comment: Поправил описание вопроса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/^[a-zа-яё]$/i.test(key)` (см. Регулярные выражения) — Будет пропускать буквы только из русского и английского алфавитов. Где `^` означает начало строки, `$` конец строки, и что-то одно из перечисленного диапазона в квадратных скобках.

```js
let text = document.getElementById('text');
let list = document.getElementById('list');

document.addEventListener('keydown', addLetter);

function addLetter(e){
  let key = e.key;
  
  if( /^[a-zа-яё]$/i.test(key) ){
    list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${key}</li>`);
  }
};
```

```html
<input id="text">
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. А присутствие инпута обязательно? Я его конечно могу застилизовать-убрать, но всё-таки.

И что это за .test?

Comment: @fromillia инпут здесь только для демо) Не нужен. А `test()` - метод для проверки регулярных выражений в строке. В общем виде: `/bubu/.test( "123bubu" )` — возвращает `true`, если совпадение найдено, иначе - `false`. А `i` в примере от слова `insensitive`, чтобы работал одинаково для заглавных и маленьких букв.